# How to remove cache for Modal?

Tags: magento2, blocks, cache, home-page, modal-popup

I created modal in homepage when user logged in.
This is my Phtml. Everything working fine but data updates only when I flush cache. How to clean cache on load page.

```
<?php 

$money = $block->walletMoney();

$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $name =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(); 
    $idd =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

    if($money>0){

     echo "<div id='custom-popup-modal' style='display:block'>
    <h1> Congragulations, <strong>$name</strong> </h1>
    <h2>Your Wallet Money of Rs.$money is Credited</h2>
    <a href='https://test.rkhomeappliances.co.in/otp/index/addmoney'>Collect Credits</a>
    </div>";

}

}
?>
<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            modalClass: 'custom-popup-modal',

        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#custom-popup-modal'));

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#custom-popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        });     
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you call phtml file? Share code..

Comment: I added block in admin->content->homepage

Answer (score 1):

**Add getCacheLifetime() in your block**

For example this phtml file call in cms home page

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" template="Vendor_Module::myfile.phtml"}}
```

In your block

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        ...
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCacheLifetime()
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

If you call phtml file with layout xml you can disable cache by **cacheable="false"**

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="myblock" template="Vendor_Module::myfile.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Prince. But this is not working

Answer (score 0):

In your module layout file where you are called you template add cacheable="false" tag so you template content will not be cached .

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\YourBlockFile" name="name of your block" template='your_template_file_name' cacheable="false"/>
```

Comment: cacheable="false"  is already there in xml

Comment: @RameshKR  It would be good if you give a try by adding content on  cms_index_index.xml layout  file and remove code  from admin cms page , make it completely module based  and then apply cacheable = false .

Comment: how to add content in homepage using   cms_index_index.xml file. can you help me I'm beginner. And where is  cms_index_index.xml file in magento flder

Comment: you can take reference from following : http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/ to create simple module .

Comment: then skip route.xml file and controller directory because you don't need it  , And run command : bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: then skip route.xml file and controller directory because you don't need it  , And run command : bin/magento setup:upgrade
It will register your module ,check listing in console , then  add file :
cms_index_index.xml  in  vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml  location 
Add following code :
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="BlockName" template="Vendor_ModuleName::templatename.phtml" cacheable="false" />

Comment: thanks for your tips. Added content to homepage using module . Everything working fine. But cache is not disabled.

Comment: I added cacheable="false"  to cms_index_index.xml but cache not disabled.